# How to get notified when a new handle to my process is opened with OpenProcess from a foreign process?

Tags: winapi, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, anti-cheat

I'm researching into game anti-cheat solutions so I can get a better grasp at how such security works. An approach used by many cheats is to use `OpenProcess` to open a process handle so they can use `ReadProcessMemory` to directly read data:

```cs
            var procHandle = Kernel32.OpenProcess(
                ProcessAccessRights.MemoryRead,
                false, process.Id
            );
```

*(snippet from a C# game cheat)*

This can be used to, for example, retrieve the positions of various entities in the game world, without needing to inject any kind of DLL; cheats that use this approach are called "external" cheats (as opposed to "internal" cheats that inject a DLL into the process).

In my anti-cheat engine, I want to detect such operations. I haven't been able to find any WinAPI methods that would call any kind of callback when a new kernel process handle is opened. If such method doesn't exist, I'm willing to use polling and enumeration (go through every single process handle to see if it's referring to my game process, and if it has the `PROCESS_VM_READ` access right. However, I couldn't find a function to get all such handles as well.

I'm pretty sure anti-cheat engines like Valve Anti-Cheat or BattleEye use this kind of detection; so, I think this would be possible from user-mode, since VAC does not install any kind of kernel driver, from my knowledge. If that is also not possible, a notification to when `ReadProcessMemory` is called would also work, but I doubt that's possible.

Any reference to a WinAPI method in the documentation that can accomplish such task would be appreciated, or a snippet ( in any language that can use WinAPI, I don't really mind :) ) that would demonstrate such behavior.

Comment: in user mode you can not got notify on handle open. if use driver - [*ObRegisterCallbacks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-obregistercallbacks)  routine registers a list of callback routines for thread, process, and desktop handle operations. so you can not only got notify but and block operation. in user mode you can enumerate all handles and found - are another processes have open handle to your process

Comment: Installing a driver seems a little intrusive (I still remember the Riot Vanguard fiasco, with them installing a driver and a lot of privacy concerns); I think I'll go with handle enumeration. I couldn't find a method that would list every object handle that relates to a process, can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: with such code - https://pastebin.com/YxNSK8cZ you can found all opened handles to your process. but need understand that system/csrss always will be have such handle. debugger, if process under debugger. another processes usually must not

Comment: @RbMm I tried doing this, but ended up getting an invalid memory location like `0xffffe38b3bcb1200` in `pshie->Handles`. I'm using C# and P/Invoke, so maybe that's the case; but I'm pretty sure it's equivalent to the C(++) code. Here's the method: https://pastebin.com/uUgDaef1 and here's the P/Invoke classes: https://pastebin.com/xNSp2J20

Comment: if it was equivalent to the C(++) - it be work ok.

Comment: Is there any documentation on the methods you used in that snippet? No MSDN page seems to be documenting the `SystemExtendedHandleInformation` functionality of `NtQuerySystemInformation`.

Comment: `SystemHandleInformationEx` and `SystemHandleInformationExEntry` is wrong on your definition. must be https://pastebin.com/DVftc33J

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249769/discussion-between-boooba-and-rbmm).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get notified when another process opens a handle to my process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75201576/how-can-i-get-notified-when-another-process-opens-a-handle-to-my-process)

Comment: As a point of clarification, BattlEye uses a kernel mode driver.