# How can I get notified when another process opens a handle to my process?

Tags: c, windows

I have been looking into ways of detecting when other processes open a handle to my process. This is what I have created so far..

**Program A**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE g_hProcess;

VOID CALLBACK WaitCallback(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired) {
    printf("Another process has opened a handle to my process!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Get a handle to the current process
    g_hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());
    if (g_hProcess == NULL) {
        printf("OpenProcess failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Register the callback function to be called when the handle is signaled
    HANDLE hWait;
    if (!RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&hWait, g_hProcess, WaitCallback, NULL, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE)) {
        printf("RegisterWaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Wait for the handle to be signaled
    WaitForSingleObject(g_hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Cleanup
    CloseHandle(g_hProcess);
    UnregisterWait(hWait);

    return 0;
}
```

Then I created another program that will open this process..

**Program B**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    HANDLE p = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 5584);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open process.\n");
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

After running `Process A` I will get the PID from process explorer. Then I will run `Process B`. The issue is that the `WaitForSingleObject()` never gets triggered. I am not sure why this is happening.

Is it possible I would get alerted when another process opens my process? Is this not how this is supposed to work?

Comment: The same question (but no answer): https://stackoverflow.com/q/74508927/2402272

Answer (score 2):

This is never going to work. A process handle is only signaled when all its threads have stopped and the process has ended.

To reliably detect when somebody tries to open a handle you need to be in kernel mode and you are basically anti-virus or malware at that point.

A less reliable method would be to call the undocumented NT API to [list handles](https://www.ired.team/miscellaneous-reversing-forensics/windows-kernel-internals/get-all-open-handles-and-kernel-object-address-from-userland). You can do this in your own process.